# How do I add my elements to my arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String email;
    private  ArrayList<Student> s;

    public Student( String n, String i, String e)
    {
        n = name; i= id; e = email;
    }
}


public class Library {

    private  ArrayList<Student> s;

    public void addStudent(Student a)
    {
        s.add(a);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Student g = new Student("John Elway", "je223", "j@gmail.com");
        Student f = new Student("Emily Harris", "emmy65", "e@yahoo.com");
        Student t = new Student("Sam Knight", "joookok", "fgdfgd@yahoo.com");

        s.addStudent(g);
        s.addStudent(f);
        s.addStudent(t);
    }
```

}

It seems like that my student objects would be added to the Student s arraylist, but it is not working that way. Is it not working due to the arraylist being in the library class instead of the Student class?

Comment: Have you tried to compile this? `s` is in a different context than your `main` method.

Comment: You need to test your code more frequently and fix problems before trying to create more code, else you'll end up with nothing but a rat's nest of problems (like we see above).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - That's exactly the problem that OP says he needs help with.

Comment: @TedHopp I read _Is it not working due to the arraylist being in the library class instead of the Student class?_ No, that has nothing to do with it. You have a static context trying to access an instance context.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I meant, OP already appears to be reporting compiler errors. igknighton -- It would help if you posted the actual compiler error message(s).

Comment: I actually didn't compile the code yet. I was getting an error due to the s situation, which you pointed out in an answer below. I compiled the code after and it worked the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

1. `main` is a `static` method, meaning that it executes outside the context of any instance of `Library`. However, `s` is an instance field of `Library`. You should either make `s` a `static` field or create an instance of `Library` and reference the field through that instance:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Library lib = new Library();
       . . .
       lib.addStudent(g);
       // etc.
   }
   ```
2. `addStudent` is not a member function of `ArrayList`; it is a member function of `Library`. Thus, you should not be coding `s.addStudent(f);`, etc.
3. You don't initialize `s`, so the first time your code tries to add an element, you will get a `NullPointerException`. You should initialize it either inline:

   ```
   private  ArrayList<Student> s = new ArrayList<Student>();
   ```

   or write a constructor for `Library` and initialize the field there.
4. Your latest change—to add `private  ArrayList<Student> s;` to the `Student` class—is on the wrong track. You will end up with a separate list of students for each student you create; surely not what you want! The list of students belongs with the `Library` where it was.
5. Your constructor for `Student` looks like it has the assignments backwards.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't be your constructor like this?

```
public Student( String n, String i, String e)
{
    name = n; id = i; email = e;
}
```

Comment: 1+ and nice pick up. igknighton has lots wrong with his code it seems.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to add directly to an instance ArrayList from a static method, something that you can't do, and more importantly, someething that you **shouldn't** do. You need to first create a Library instance within your main method before you can call methods on it.

```
Library myLibrary = new Library();
myLibrary.add(new Student("John Elway", "je223", "j@gmail.com"));
// ... etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Library {

private  ArrayList<Student> s = new ArrayList<Student>(); //you forgot to create ArrayList

public void addStudent(Student a)
{
    s.add(a);
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Student g = new Student("John Elway", "je223", "j@gmail.com");
    Student f = new Student("Emily Harris", "emmy65", "e@yahoo.com");
    Student t = new Student("Sam Knight", "joookok", "fgdfgd@yahoo.com");
    Library  library = new Library ();
    library.addStudent(g);
    library.addStudent(f);
    library.addStudent(t);
}
```

and change your constructor like this

```
public Student( String n, String i, String e)
{
        this.name = n;
        this.id = i; 
        this.email = e;
}
```

Comment: At least please get rid of the `s.addStudent(...)` crap in your code.